# Windows 10 - Display Driver Stopped Responding and Has Recovered. How can I fix it?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, amd-radeon

I have ati radeon 5700 and after I upgraded to windows 10 I have problems with it.
Sometimes it says: "Display Driver Stopped Responding and Has Recovered".
And in other cases my movies have some strange white lines like it was a movie from 50 years ago. and sometimes the colors of the screens turn to green\purple like 4bit old colors.

Do you know what could be the problem?

EDIT: I checked and I have the latest driver version

EDIT2: I uploaded Dxdiag file [Here](http://www.filedropper.com/dxdiag_4)

Comment: Firstly try updating the driver. I had this problem with an Intel HD graphics driver in Windows 10 Build 1511 - Am currently using a Beta driver that stopped that occurring but still get odd flashes from time to time.

Comment: already did and I have the latest

Comment: @11alex11 - So you have [these](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy3&os=Windows+10+-+64) drivers installed?  Can you provide a dxdiag report for us?

Comment: I added link to a file containing Dxdiag info.
I don't know what drivers I have but I run the Auto Detector and it said that I have the latest drivers

Comment: Any luck with this one? Experiencing identical symptoms with Intel HD 4600 and Windows 10.0.10586.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue and none of the given solutions worked.

I have now fixed it. I used nvflash and changed the firmware on my Palit GTX760 from:
Palit.GTX760.2048.130724.rom to Palit.GTX760.2048.130703.rom
Now everything works fine and I can play Rise Of The Tomb Raider with DX12 again.

If nothing else works for you, firmware may be the issue.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. Palit GTX760 != ati radeon 570

Comment: They are both graphics cards and both have firmware. I searched your site and found nothing but the same generic rubbish everyone gives:

Comment: Update drivers, run sfc, reinstall windows and eventually buy a new card. NOBODY suggested rolling back firmware and it fixed the issue for me instantly. Therefor my answer stands: IF NOTHING ELSE WORKS FOR YOU, Firmware (for your specific card) may be the issue.